# How change the database journal mode

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite-journal-mode

When I create a DataBase on my apply, I have this error:

> Could not change the database journal mode of
>   '/data/data/example/databases/exemple' from 'wal' to 'PERSIST' because
>   the database is locked.  This usually means that there are other open
>   connections to the database which prevents the database from enabling
>   or disabling write-ahead logging mode.  Proceeding without changing
>   the journal mode.

I don't know the solution, can you help me?

Comment: Nobody?

How do I change the database mode?
Before, on my Logcat I have this message:

SQLiteLog >(5) statement aborts at 2: [PRAGMA journal_mode=PERSIST]